# 6-channel piezo buffer jfet circuit

Tags: buffer, jfet, piezo, mixer

Even though I'm a total beginner at electronics, I've decided to build a 6-channel piezo pickup buffer/mixer unit, for a stringed instrument. It should fit into a typically sized electronics cavity, and be powered by a 9 volt battery. Gain boost is not necessary, but I'll take it, if possible :-)

One of my questions, is how to best sum 6 of these circuits together.

[image]

Before summing the outputs together, I was thinking of adding 50k trimpots, to allow for level adjustments.
Ideally, the summing/mixing section, would also be jfet based (j201).

I've built the stratoblaster circuit before, and was wondering, if that could be used as a mixing stage?
[image]

All very naive assumptions, I know :-)

So, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to use an OP Amp, a summing operational amplifier. "The Summing (Operational) Amplifier - Electronics Tutorials":
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Is an op amp based circuit better than a jfet one?

Comment: #bankschreiner, actually my limited experience of using OpAmp is LM386 audio amplifier, and LM310 OpAmp comparator. I also played with general purpose, small signal MOSFET 2N7000. I think 2N5457 JFET should be good for audio applications, though I have the feeling that JFET sounds old fashioned, and is not so popular as MOSFET, especially power MOSFET is so common nowadays. Anyway, I think @analogsystemsrf's advice is good.

Comment: thank you #tlfong01

Comment: You are welcome. Have a great project! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all modern opamps are CMOSFET input, which will provide the same picoAmpere input currents that JFETs achieve.

To select an opamp, determine if you need

- Rail_to_Rail inputs (such as 0v to +3.3v)
- Rail_to_Rail output (often spec'd as "within 0.01v of rail, for 10Kohm load)
- unity_gain stable (needed if you only use for Gain = +1) and for 100pF Cload
- of adequate slew_rate ( 2 volt peak_peak output at 20,000Hz needs more than 120,000 volts/second , or 0.12 v/microsecond). So pick the default of 0.5v/uS , or faster.